# Map from torus to itself which is a covering map except at finitely many points

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, complex-geometry

Let $T=S^1\times S^1$ the torus and $M\subset T$ a finite subset. Let $f\colon T\to T$ a surjective continuous map such that on $f^{-1}(T\setminus M)$ it is a covering map. Does this imply that $f$ itself is a covering map?

If we equip source and target with (possibly different) complex structures and $f$ is complex analytic, then the claim follows from Riemann-Hurwitz. But is the purely topological statement also true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a counterexample.

For each $m \in M$ let $\alpha_m \subset T$ be an arc (a compact subset homeomorphic to $[0,1]$) such that $m \in \alpha_m$, and such that the arcs $\alpha_m$ are pairwise disjoint. Let $A = \bigcup_{m \in M} \alpha_m$.

Then there is a surjective continuous map $f : T \to T$ such that $f(\alpha_m)=m$ for each $m \in M$, and such that $f$ restricts to a homeomorphism from $T-A$ to $T-M$, hence $T-A = f^{-1}(T-M)$.

But since $f^{-1}(m)=\alpha_m$, the map $f$ is not a covering map.